# Moving wordpress site from subdomain to domain with 1 caveat

Tags: wordpress

I already have wordpress installed in my root, but I haven't built anything on it.
All these while I have been building on my subdomain, which is also using wordpress.

Now I have come to the conclusion to move everything I have from the subdomain to the root. 
Are there anything I should take note of? Should I remove the wordpress installation that is in my root?

I'm using cpanel @ hostgator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the wordpress installation that is in your root directory, then copy all the files from the sub-domain's folder to your root directory. You should note that before moving the files, log into the existing Wordpress dashboard and under Settings -> General you need to change the URLs of your site first, otherwise you won't be able to log in once your site is moved. That's it.

Comment: but what will happen to the database? will my users get coped over as well?

Comment: @Kannan Your website is still on the same hosting, so no matter in which directory the files are, they will still be able to access the same database - That's why there's no need to move it. You only move the database if you're moving the site to a completely different server.